# How do I send the data to JTable with String and Array

Tags: java

This is my first question from stock overflow exited a bit I have made a class and `JTextField` for a class and I have a problem  once I click the complete order Button it should save all the data and information nice and cool in `JTable` I have been thought to use `String[]` and `Object` but basically I have no Idea how to do it ???

and this is my software class

```
class Software extends Products {

    private float ram;
    private float processor;

    //SoftwareProducts sf = new SoftwareProducts();
    public Software(int productID, String productName,
                    int productYear, String productPublishHouse) {
        super(productID, productName, productYear, productPublishHouse);

        this.ram = ram;
        this.processor = processor;

   //super(productID,productName, productYear, productPublishHouse);
    }

    public void setRam(float ram) {

        this.ram = ram;
    }

    public float getRam() {

        return ram;
    }

    public void setProcessor(float processor) {

        this.processor = processor;
    }

    public float getProcessor() {

        return processor;
    }

}
//int productID,String productName,int productYear,
String   productPublishHouse
```

and this is my Customer Order Class which Basically I need to run my JTable from it and make String and Object

```
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.table.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class CustomerOrder extends JPanel
                implements ActionListener {

                                //JButton asd = new JButton("BUTTON");
    //JTextField productID;
    //JTextField productName;
    //JTextField productCost;
    //JTextField productPYear;
    //JTextField productPHouse;
    JButton showOrder;

    DefaultListModel<String> model = new DefaultListModel<>();
    JList<String> orderList = new JList(model);
    JTable softwareTabel = new JTable();

                             //DefaultTableModel tableModel = new DefaultTableModel(0, 1);
    public CustomerOrder() {

                                 //super();
                                // JLabel toLabel=new JLabel("Product ID: ");
        //JTextField to=new JTextField();
        setLayout(new FlowLayout());

        /* 
                             productName = new JTextField(12);
                add(productName);

                productCost = new JTextField(12);
                add(productCost);

                productPYear = new JTextField(12);
                add(productPYear);


                productPHouse = new JTextField(12);
                add(productPHouse);

         */
        showOrder = new JButton("SHOW ORDER");
        showOrder.setSize(25, 40);
        showOrder.addActionListener(this);
        add(showOrder);

    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if (e.getSource() == showOrder) {
            model.removeAllElements();

            /*  GridLayout exLayout = new GridLayout(3, 3);

                         JLabel ram,processor; 

                         ram = new JLabel("RAM");
                         processor = new JLabel("Processor");
                         String softwaredata[] = {"ID","RAM","Processor","Product ID","Product Name","Product Year","Product Year","Product PublishHouse"};

                         JPanel panel = new JPanel();
                         panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(8,   3));

                         add(ram);
                         add(processor);

                         JTable table = new JTable();*/
                         //DeafultTableModel dm = new DeafultTableModel(0,0);
            //String header[] = new String[] {"RAM", "Processor","ProductID","Product Name","Product Year","Product Publish House"}; 
            //dm.setColumnIdentifiers(header);
            //Object[][] software = new Object[8][3];
                            //model.addRow(orderList.toArray());
            int x = 0;
            while (x < main.softwareList.size()) {
                //./model.addElement(main.softwareList.get(x).getproductYear());
                model.addElement("" + main.softwareList.get(x).getproductID());
                model.addElement("" + main.softwareList.get(x).getRam());
                model.addElement("" + main.softwareList.get(x).getProcessor());
                model.addElement("" + main.softwareList.get(x).getproductID());
                model.addElement(main.softwareList.get(x).getproductName());
                model.addElement("" + main.softwareList.get(x).getproductYear());
                model.addElement(main.softwareList.get(x).getproductPublishHouse());
                                 //model.addElement(main.softwareList.get(x).getproductID());*/              

                x++;

                            //System.out.println("as");
            }
            ArrayList<String> table1 = new ArrayList();

            ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> table2 = new ArrayList();
            table1.add("Product ID");
            table1.add("RAM");
            table1.add("Processor");
            table1.add("Product Name");
            table1.add("Product Year");
            table1.add("Product PHouse");

            Object[] software = table1.toArray();
            String[][] softwarest = new String[table1.size()][];

            int i = 0;
            for (List<String> next : table2) {

                softwarest[i++] = next.toArray(new String[next.size()]);
            }

            JTable newTable = new JTable(softwarest, software);

            JFrame frame = new JFrame();
            frame.getContentPane().add(new JScrollPane(newTable));
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

                                 //add(model);
            add(orderList);
                        //Object[] column = {"RAM:", "Processor:"};
            //Object[][] data = {{"RAM:", "Processor:"}};
            //JTable table = new JTable();
            //table.setShowGrid(false);
            //table.setTableHeader(null); 

        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Start by taking a closer look at [How to Use Tables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html).  Also you might like to have a look at [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9554636/418556)

Comment: In the future, consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This is not a code dump, but an example of what you are doing which highlights the problem you are having. This will result in less confusion and better responses

Answer (score 1):

Since you already have a POJO which wraps the basic properties of your `Produce`, a simpler (and more reusable) solution would be to create a dedicated `ProductTableModel` for it...

```
public static class ProductTableModel extends AbstractTableModel {

    protected static final String[] COLUMN_NAMES = {"Product ID",
        "RAM",
        "Processor",
        "Product Name",
        "Product Year",
        "Product PHouse"};

    private List<Product> products;

    public ProductTableModel(List<Product> products) {
        this.products = new ArrayList<>(products);
    }

    @Override
    public int getRowCount() {
        return products.size();
    }

    @Override
    public int getColumnCount() {
        return COLUMN_NAMES.length;
    }

    @Override
    public String getColumnName(int column) {
        return COLUMN_NAMES[column];
    }

    public Product getProductAt(int row) {
        return products.get(row);
    }

    @Override
    public Object getValueAt(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
        Product product = getProductAt(rowIndex);
        Object value = null;
        switch (columnIndex) {
            case 0:
                value = product.getID();
                break;
            case 1:
                value = product.getRAM();
                break;
            case 2:
                value = product.getProcessor();
                break;
            case 3:
                value = product.getName();
                break;
            case 4:
                value = product.getYear();
                break;
            case 5:
                value = product.getPHouse();
                break;
        }
        return value;
    }

}
```

Then you could simply do something like...

```
ProductTableModel model = new ProductTableModel(listOfProducts);
productTable.setModel(model); // A JTable
```